# Android Navigation findNavController when NavHost is not in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

I have an activity which holds `FragmentContainerView`. In the `FragmentContainerView` I have a `NavHostFragment`. I want to `setupActionBarWithNavController` in the `NavHostFragment`.

```
class MenuNavHostFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    fun setup(activity: MainActivity) {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.fragment_menu_nav_host)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(activity, navController)
}
```

in MainActivity.kt

```
private lateinit var menuNavHostFragment: MenuNavHostFragment
private fun setupNavigation() {
    menuNavHostFragment = MenuNavHostFragment()
    menuNavHostFragment.setup(this)
}
```

in `fragment_menu_nav_host`:

```
...
tools:context=".View.MenuNavHostFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_menu_nav_host"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
...
```

Which results in the following error message: *ID does not reference a View inside this Activity*

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bla.bla/com.bla.bla.View.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
    at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:2686)
    at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
    at com.bla.bla.View.MenuNavHostFragment.setup(MenuNavHostFragment.kt:36)
    at com.bla.bla.View.MainActivity.setupNavigation(MainActivity.kt:38)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think, your MenuNavHostFragment is not created when you are calling `setup` method

Comment: use `findNavController()` from `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx` https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#navigation

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! @VaikundamRaghul your answer is correct.

Comment: @Casper Linderberg, I have added it as answer. Please accept the answer so that it will benefit others who faces the similar issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment in which `navHostFragment` is defined has to be created before calling the `Navigation.findNavController()` method to avoid this exception.